# Как перевести базу данных из ANSI в UTF-8 ?

Tags: dbase, django

На виндовсе когда создаешь БД в консоли она автоматически имеет формат ANSI, как пересохранить,или сразу сохранить в UTF-8? Пробовал открыть как блокнот и там сохранить в UTF-8 но тогда перестает работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

создавайте БД так:

```
CREATE DATABASE `dbname` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Для переноса данных django используйте [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) и [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata)

Comment: А если создана в ANSI уже никак в utf8 не конвертнуть?

Comment: Переведите свой комментарий на русский язык (с мелкомягкого). Переводить из ANSI в UTF8 не надо, символы ANSI являются подмножеством utf8. Другое дело, что на мелкомягком языке символы ANSI -- это что-то другое. Какая-то 8-битная кодировка (cp1251?), содержащая ANSI и что-то ещё.